# PHP MYSQL Returning Results When Booking Spans Into Next Month

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, union

I am editing a booking system's code (nation hotel theme in wordpress) in order to try to fix the issue that when the user selects a check-out date in the month after the check-in date it returns 0 results.

Here is the original code from the reservations page:

```
$dayFirst = date("d",strtotime($_POST["check-in"]));
$monthFirst = date("m",strtotime($_POST["check-in"]));
$yearFirst = date("Y",strtotime($_POST["check-in"]));
$dayLast = date("d",strtotime($_POST["check-out"]));
$monthLast = date("m",strtotime($_POST["check-out"]));
$yearLast = date("Y",strtotime($_POST["check-out"]));

$price = $wpdb->get_row( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT min_price FROM {$wpdb->prefix}nation_booking_calendars WHERE id='%d'",
    $calID
    ) );
$minPrice = $price->min_price;
                                               $roomAvailty = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
    "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}nation_booking_availability 
    WHERE calendar_id='%d' 
        AND day >= $dayFirst 
        AND month >= $monthFirst 
        AND year >= $yearFirst 
        AND day < $dayLast 
        AND month <= $monthLast 
        AND year <= $yearLast 
        AND availability >= %d ",
    $calID,$_POST["room-number"]
    ) );

if ( count($roomAvailty) == count( $dateRange ) ) {
    $roomAvailable = true;
}
```

My problem is that count($roomAvailty) returns 0 when the booking goes over into the next month.

I figured that the problem was how the mysql select statement worked so I changed that part to the following:

```
if($monthFirst==$monthLast) {                       
    $roomAvailty = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "SELECT * 
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}nation_booking_availability 
        WHERE calendar_id='%d' 
            AND day >= $dayFirst 
            AND month >= $monthFirst 
            AND year >= $yearFirst 
            AND day < $dayLast 
            AND month <= $monthLast 
            AND year <= $yearLast 
            AND availability >= %d ",
        $calID,$_POST["room-number"]
        ) );
}
else {
    $roomAvailty = $wpdb->get_results( $wpdb->prepare( 
        "(SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}nation_booking_availability 
            WHERE calendar_id='%d' 
                AND day >= $dayFirst 
                AND day <= $maxdays 
                AND month = $monthFirst 
                AND year = $yearFirst 
                AND availability >= %d)
        UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}nation_booking_availability 
            WHERE calendar_id='%d' 
                AND day >= $mindays 
                AND day < $dayLast 
                AND month = $monthLast
                AND year = $yearLast 
                AND availability >= %d)
        UNION ALL
            (SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}nation_booking_availability 
                WHERE calendar_id='%d' 
                    AND month > $monthFirst 
                    AND month < $monthLast 
                    AND year = $yearFirst 
                    AND availability >= %d) ",
        $calID,$_POST["room-number"]
        ) );
}
```

But its still returning 0 results. Any ideas? Here is a picture of my database:

```
id  calendar_id day month year availability price
101 11          2   9     2014 1            95
102 11          3   9     2014 1            95
103 11          4   9     2014 1            95
104 11          5   9     2014 1            95
105 11          6   9     2014 1            95
106 11          7   9     2014 1            95
107 11          8   9     2014 1            95
108 11          9   9     2014 1            95
109 11         10   9     2014 1            95
```

Comment: Why do you have separate columns for day, month, and year?

Comment: Hi Strawberry - no idea I'm afraid. Seems silly to me but I'm editing someone elses code/database structure.

Comment: Not sure of the actual fix but my solution was to remove the union parts of the statements, run the sql queries individually and then merge the resulting arrays with php.

Comment: That's great. So, now's your chance to fix that.